# Ajax afte file upload to update record

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, file-upload

I am trying to update a record in my table after an ajax file upload.

The file upload works fine and I have an function uploadFinished that returns the path to the uploaded file on the server.
In my controller I have a function to update the current project.

```
if(!empty($this->data)){
            if($this->Project->save($this->data)){
                if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
                    $this->render('success', 'ajax');
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Message Sent');
                    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
                }
            }
        }
```

I am having problems with setting up the ajax request in the uploadFinished function.
I have searched the web and I think I need to use something like this:

```
    $.ajax({                    
    url:'/projects/set_ref',
    type:"POST",                                        
    data:data
});
```

But I am not quite sure how to set the data. I would really appreciate it if some one could put me in the right direction.
Cheers!

Comment: Short history is that you want to upload a file using AJAX, right?

Comment: You say that you are successfully uploading a file with ajax (which is possible in IE10 and other modern browsers), where does this second ajax request come in? Is it in the success callback of the previous $.ajax?

Comment: Alexander I am not looking to do a file upload, I have managed to do that and it works. What I am trying to do is insert the path and file name into the database after the upload has succeeded. Kevin, yes the second ajax request is in the success callback

Comment: Now, what do you mean by *"But I am not quite sure how to set the data"*? what data do you want to send?

Comment: I want to send the path and filename of the file. I have this in the success callback. var response holds the data if the upload was successful.

Comment: Ok, so, put that in key/value pairs as an object and pass that as data. `var data = { "foo":"bar","barfoo":"foobar" };` There should be good example in the $.ajax documentation of that. I'm surprised you're stuck on that after getting ajax file upload working.

Comment: Thanks gonna try it out, well I have a working site that I am trying to rebuild in cakphp that I am new at, and it is past 1am :) will let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

I will post how I solved this problem with the help I got from Kevin B. to help anyone facing the same problem.

To pass information via ajax to the controller I created an ajax request in the success callback of the image upload.
The image upload function returned the path+filename of the file on the server in the response variable, which I could then pass to the controller:

```
var data = {"ref":response};

$.ajax({                    
url:'/projects/set_ref',
type:"POST",                                        
data:data
});
```